# has_one relationship not working on new/create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one  :user_tms, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_tms
end

class UserTms < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the UsersController I have this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_user_tms
end
```

And the user form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:company_id, @companies, :id, :name, :include_blank => true) %>

  <%= f.fields_for(:user_tms) do |tms_form| %>
    <%= tms_form.collection_select(:department, @departments, :id, :description) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Pretty basic stuff I think, but when submitting the form I get the error:

```
User tms user can't be blank
```

And the weird thing is that when editing an exisiting user, everything works fine. Any idea what is going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the log of request and SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it is unusual to has a class end with an "s".

What is the table name?  user_tms or user_tmses.  I would set the plural name in your model.

I could have missed something else if so I'll delete.  It is best to have a better model name for new developers though.  tms doesn't mean much to most people.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, because the same problem happens with model 'user_mob' with table 'user_mobs'.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is really weird because I thought rails is taking care of this automatically but it seems your nested model is missing the reference to the 'nester'. Try to supply it manually.

```
@user.user_tms.user = @user
```

You have to do this in the create action ie. where the record gets saved.

What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what's wrong, I had a method causing some trouble with a false return value, which interfered with the normal handling of the relations with these two models.